# Regex for number with minimum value and thousand separator

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression to validate a number that is either just a 0 OR at least 1000 and that also allows a comma for a thousand separator.

The closest I've got is this which validates the number part correctly but not the thousand separator.

```
^(([1-9]{1}[0-9]{3,})|0)$
```

**Test cases:**

Allow:

```
0
1000
50000
1,000
50,000
99,992,001
```

Not allow:

```
00
0001
999
1,1,00
1.000.000
anystring
```

Comment: This isn't an answer, but why are you using a regex for this.  Surely parsing it to a float and then checking the min and max would be easier to deal with?

Comment: @scragar - No, it doesn't (according to [regexpal](http://www.regexpal.com/).) Besides, you should be posting answers in the answers section, not the comments.

Comment: I wrote the question in a rush so it isn't entirely accurate. I needed to validate a string rather than a number. It was for use in an MVC form validator to prevent users from entering invalid amounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly: think very carefully before you use regular expressions for things such as this! Regular expressions may (correctly) seem like a powerful tool but by using them you're sacrificing some powerful number-manipulation tools and also clarity/maintainability of your code.

However, if there are reasons for you wanting to stick to regular expressions, I think this one will do what you want:

```
^(0|[1-9]\d{0,2}((\d{3})+|(,\d{3})+))$
```

It chooses:

- Either a zero; OR
- A non-zero digit, then up to two other digits, followed by batches of digits three at a time either all comma-separated or none.

You can see it working here: http://regex101.com/r/nG7rL5

Comment: Very elegant solution, thanks. I also needed a version that would do the same but be either 0 or at least 100. I used this ^(0|[1-9]\d{0,2}((\d{3})+|(,\d{3})+)|[1-9]\d{2})$

Answer (score 1):

This regex should work:

```
^(?:0|[1-9][0-9]{3,}|[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(?:,[0-9]{3})+)$
```

#### [Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/xP9mM5)

Answer (score -3):

Try:

```
^(([1-9]\d*(,?\d{3})+)|0)$
```

Comment: Hm, unfortunately I don't think this will work - it will match something such as "1000,000" which although might officially working with the asker's brief probably shouldn't thinking about the use case.